# Is comparison of a topic with other religions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I thought this question was asked before on meta. but couldn't find a link. So, I am asking it.

Is it on-topic to ask for differences/relation by comparing other religion similar topics?

Something like:

- [The differences between “Nirvana” in Buddhism and “Moksha” in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1980/93)

Comment: It should be on topic , else then what is the use of the tag "Buddhism"?

Comment: I don't think that the question specified should be off-topic. It is just asking how Hindu concept of Moksha differs from the Buddhist Niravana concept. Questions asking about Hinduism's explanation of a concept found in other religion (which may or may not be same) should be on-topic.

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran please post it as answer.. we will see. :)

Comment: Brief thought: I think that comparisons with the religions that grew out of Hinduism (i.e. Buddhism, Jainism) should definitely be on-topic. I'm ambivalent about comparisons to other religions (e.g. Christianity, Islam). I'll write a longer answer once I've thought about this more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that the question specified should be off-topic. It is just asking how Hindu concept of Moksha differs from the Buddhist Niravana concept. Questions asking about Hinduism's explanation of a concept found in other religion (which may or may not be same) should be on-topic.

For example, Ramayana is accepted in Jainism and Buddhism also, but in a slightly different version. There are also Thai, Cambodian, Indonesian and Malaysian versions of it. If someone asks a question regarding a particular difference between two such versions, it would definitely be on-topic.

The question mentioned in this post is similar to the above example and is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46339431#46339431

Comment: @Paṇḍyā A meta discussion >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> chat message with just a ping. It would have been more helpful what you meant by linking a chat message. Should we reply to it? Should we read it? Star it? What?