# Is the question "Hinduism ever tried to enfold Christianity" valid for the site? Please explain why

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Is the following question valid for the site? Yes or No? Why?

- [Has Hinduism ever tried to enfold Christianity (or other semitic religions)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7553)

There is lot of comparison of religions going on in both the question and the accepted answer.

Similar question was asked on meta before:

- [Is comparison of a topic with other religions on-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198)

Comment: "Have serious branches of Indian philosophy (i.e. Hinduism's "theology") ever argued in this way, or is Hinduism perhaps not interested in establishing such hegemony over foreign religions?" may be valid question.